# Getting 302 response code in widget ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, widget, http-status-code-302

I am working on a MVC application in which when have an option to request password reset email. When we got the email with the link, that link will redirect to the welcome page where we will enter Password and Confirm password and then we will click continue. Once all the validations of Welcome page passed, the user will be redirected to Dashboard page where we are loading few widgets through ajax calls. In one of our production environment these ajax calls are giving 302 http code instead of 200. Due to this behavior the widgets are loading either welcome page or login page as their content instead of original content. From the code base, no where we are redirecting to Welcome page or login page from any of the widget ajax calls. As this is happening in only production environment but not in local, it became hard to debug.

Can anyone please help guide me on how to figure out the cause of redirection.

Thanks....

Comment: Does your Action methods return **JSON**? Are you sure you are not using `RedirectToAction` or `RedirectToPage`, etc ? Better double-check your Action Methods return type.

Comment: @Mohi I am sure that we are not using RedirectToAction or RedirectToPage. If we are using those the issue should replicate from localhost also right. but the issue only replicating only one prod environment.

Comment: It's better you spend some part of your code inside the post, so everyone can see and help you here.